# SQL: Replace +1 with +44

Tags: sql

I've written a query to find phone numbers. Due to a bug in the system, some phone numbers are appearing with +1 rather than +44 at the beginning. How can I replace +1 with +44 while retaining the following sequence of digits?

I think this would be a case when clause:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN "+1%%%%%%%%%%%" THEN "+44%%%%%%%%%%" ELSE "+44%%%%%%%%%%" END AS PHONE
```

I would appreciate the help as I keep on getting an error when trying to run the query with this.

Thank you!

Comment: Tag with the database you are using.

Comment: It should be simply `REPLACE(number, '+1', '+44')`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no further `+`s in the number, just use `replace()`:

```
select replace(number, '+1', '+44')
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a13d7/4)

```
CREATE TABLE Mytable (Phone varchar(20))
INSERT INTO Mytable(Phone) VALUES ('+1123456789123')
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT Phone,
CASE WHEN Phone LIKE '+1%' THEN replace(Phone, '+1', '+44') ELSE Phone END AS NewPhone
FROM Mytable
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a13d7/4/0)**:

```
|          Phone |        NewPhone |
|----------------|-----------------|
| +1123456789123 | +44123456789123 |
```